# Promise is resolved but code stops in await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I followed Mozilla's [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). I created a function with a `Promise` inside. The `Promise` is resolved when the selector appears on the page (if not, the function runs again). Then the code should continue after `await`:

```
;(async () => {
  const titleSel = '.playbackSoundBadge__titleLink'
  document.querySelector(titleSel).click()
  const moreSel = 'button[title="More"]'
  await waitForEl(moreSel)
  console.log('after await')

  function waitForEl(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log(selector)
      if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
        console.log('resolved')
        resolve('resolved')
      } else {
        console.log('rejected')
        setTimeout(() => {
          waitForEl(selector)
        }, 100)
      }
    })
  }
})()
```

But strangely, `'resolved'` is logged. But the code after `await` doesn't run. In other words, `'after await'` is never logged.

Why is this, and how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with your recursive call in the `setTimeout`. You call `waitForEl` recursively but you never do anything with the returned promise. In this path, the original promise (the one form the first call) is never updated (it's pending). Thus, the client is waiting. Try awaiting the new promise and when it's fulfilled, resolve the original one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `waitForEl(selector)` to `resolve`:

```js
;(async () => {
  const moreSel = '.more'
  await waitForEl(moreSel)
  console.log('after await')

  function waitForEl(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log(selector)
      if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
        console.log('resolved')
        resolve('resolved')
      } else {
        console.log('rejected')
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(waitForEl(selector)) // here
        }, 1000)
      }
    })
  }
})()

const btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.textContent = "add more";
const more = document.createElement("div");
more.textContent = "more";
more.classList.add("more");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.appendChild(more);
});
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

In your code `await waitForEl(moreSel)` was never settled thus the log below couldn't be executed. If you pass a promise to `resolve`, the original promise will "bind" its fate to the passed one.

Answer (score 2):

> But strangely, 'resolved' is logged.
>   ...
>   Why is this

`waitForEl` is called "recursively" (it schedules a call of itself via `setTimeout`). Every call to `waitForEl` creates a promise, so you are creating multiple promises. The 'resolved' you see in the console is from *one* of those promises. You should also see one or more 'reject' messages.

The problem is that the "parent"/"top" promise is never resolved, because are not doing anything with the return value here:

```
waitForEl(selector)
```

The function returns a promise, but you are not doing anything with it, thus never resolving the promise that called this function.

An easy solution would be

```
waitForEl(selector).then(resolve)
```

But that also means you are creating promises recursively. It seems unnecessary to do this. Just define a simple function inside the promise that calls itself:

```
 function waitForEl(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log(selector)
      (function check()
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
          console.log('resolved')
          resolve('resolved')
        } else {
          console.log('rejected')
          setTimeout(check, 100);
        }
      }());
    })
  }
```

You should still add some condition that will reject the promise after some time, so it doesn't call `setTimeout` forever.